# The Bootstrap tooltip function missing when change to other page using Datatable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, datatables, jquery-ui-tooltip

```
VISIT http://jsfiddle.net/housekeepings/qx5a4wf3/3/
```

The Tooltip function can work well on the first page,
[image]

but failed when change to page two!
[image]
How can redraw the tooltip on the other page?

Comment: I would recommend looking at the draw event for DataTables and apply the tooltip there.  This fires every time the table reloads so would include; paging, sorting, filtering etc https://datatables.net/reference/event/draw

Comment: @PaulZepernick Thank you~It works! Though the responsive "+" place still not working~But other paging is work well~So nice!

Comment: I added it as an answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tooltip is being applied when the dom is ready on page load and is not being re-applied to new elements coming into the dom when the table view is drawn again.  DataTables has a [draw event](http://datatables.net/reference/event/draw) that is triggered when the state of the table changes.  A listener can be attached to this event and have the tooltip applied when the draw event fires.

```
$('#table_id').DataTable({responsive: true,}).on("draw", function() {
     $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```